# RxJS filter() operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, rxjs5, rxjs-dom

I am trying to find the cleanest solution to use `filter()` operator in order to filter my observables.

Here I am replicating the service call to get a `femaleList` separately

```
export class MyComp implements OnInit {

    maleList: IContact[] = [];
    femaleList: IContact[] = [];    

    constructor(private _contactService: ContactService) { }
    ngOnInit() : void {
        this._contactService.getContacts()
         .filter(male => male.gender === 'M')
        subscribe(maleList => this.maleList = maleList);

        this._contactService.getContacts()
         .filter(female => female.gender === 'F')
        subscribe(femaleList => this.femaleList = femaleList);
     } }
```

**Contactlist**

```
 [{
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Todd",
      "gender" : "M"
    }, {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "Lillian",
      "gender" : "F"
    }]
```

Is there any option in RxJS operators with single observable to assign to two variables.

How can i filter the Contacts and assign it to `maleList` and `femaleList` using **RxJS** `filter()` operator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a filter:

```
this._contactService.getContacts()
  .subscribe(person => {
    if(person.gender === 'F'){
      this.femaleList.push(person);
    } else {
      this.maleList.push(person);
    }
```

Comment: Can we filter data before subscribe the service?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a single Observable and subscribe to it with two different Observers you'll need to use `share()` or `shareReplay()` (which is in RxJS 5 now available only with `.publishReplay().refCount()`) (See https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/publish.md and https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md).

```
let data = [{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Todd",
    "gender" : "M"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Lillian",
    "gender" : "F"
}];

let maleList = [];
let femaleList = [];

let source = Observable.defer(() => {
        console.log('Observable.defer');
        return Observable.from(data);
    })
    .publishReplay()
    .refCount();

source
    .filter(male => male.gender === 'M')
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(list => maleList = list);

source
    .filter(male => male.gender === 'F')
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(list => femaleList = list);

console.log('maleList', maleList);
console.log('femaleList', femaleList);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/hapofu/edit?js,console

This prints to console:

```
Observable.defer
maleList [ { id: 1, name: 'Todd', gender: 'M' } ]
femaleList [ { id: 2, name: 'Lillian', gender: 'F' } ]
```

Both these subscribers share the same connection to `source` and at the same time the response is "replayed" (if you subscribe after it was first emitted it'll reemitted without subscribing to the `source` again).

Note that the items from `filter()` are emitted one at the time. That's why I used `toArray()` to collect all values and reemit them as a single array. Alternatively I could call eg. `maleList.push()` with every value.

Btw, there's also [`partition()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-partition) operator that you could use instead of `filter()` to avoid creating two subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash:

*.partition(collection, [predicate=*.identity]);

https://lodash.com/docs/#partition

This returns 2 arrays, one where the values evaluate to false & the other to true. Just use 'gender' to build the evaluation.